# Accessing the QSYSOPR message from the DB2 iSeries console when it is locked

Tags: networking, ibm-midrange

For a variety of reasons yesterday we had to shut off access to the router that our iSeries connects to, we did this in an attempt to prevent a full shut down of the iSeries.

Today when we reconnected the network we still had issues connecting to the iSeries.  So we went to the console and could connect there.
So, I found instruction on how to get the status of the network:

```
GO CFGTCP
OPTION 1 (at the menu)
```

and the IP address shown above indicate an error message RCYPND on our main connection.  So we looked at the help and followed the instructions for getting to the CFGTCPSTS found our connection and tried to vary it on.  We got a message that it was already varied on.  So we decided to vary it off and then back on.  And that's where we are stuck now.

We get a message on the console that we need to answer a message to QSYSOPR except we can't get out of the CFGTCPSTS screen where we tried to vary off the device.

Can anyone give me a clue how to get to the QSYSOPR message from the console when it is locked on another process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Press <kbd>shift</kbd> <kbd>esc</kbd> and type <kbd>6</kbd> <kbd>enter</kbd> on the system attention line to access the QSYSOPR message queue.

You can use option <kbd>2</kbd> to end the current job step if you are stuck.

You may need to restart tcp and the host servers with the command `STRTCP` and `STRHOSTSVR SERVER(*ALL)`.

If you need more help I would be happy to provide a no charge consult to help you out of the emergency.  You can P/M me at the address in my profile.

Comment: unfortunately this came too late (I know you answered within an hour but we needed minute response!)...we ended up pulling the plug and doing an IPL.  I have forwarded this tip to our AS400 person and will definitely keep your information for future issues!